React 18.x: Unexpected double render when setting same state value twice
I'm testing the behavior of setState in React 18.x and I'm observing a unexpected result. I set the same state value twice in a row, and I expect the render function to only run once. However, I see the render function running twice.
Here's the code:
import * as React from "react";
import { Component, useState } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

function App() {
  const [val, setVal] = useState(1);
  console.log("render", val);
  return (
    <div>
      {val}
      <button id="btn" onClick={() => setVal(2)}>
        click
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<App />);

setTimeout(() => {
  document.getElementById("btn").click();
}, 2000);
setTimeout(() => {
  document.getElementById("btn").click();
}, 3000);
setTimeout(() => {
  document.getElementById("btn").click();
}, 4000);

And here's the output:
render 1
render 2
render 2

You can reproduce this issue in this Codesandbox Link.
Can anyone help me understand why this is happening?

here is the same question: react-hooks-usestate-setvalue-still-rerender-one-more-time-when-value-is-equal
